# CakePHP Login redirect admin/user

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am using the login function as followed.

```
public function login()
{

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            if ($user['warning'] == false) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                if ($this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin') {
                    if(isset($this->Auth->redirectUrl)){
                        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                    }
                    else return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'adresses','action' => 'adminindex']);


                } elseif ($this->Auth->user('role') == 'user') {
                    if(isset($this->Auth->redirectUrl)){
                        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                    }
                    else return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'adresses','action' => 'index']);
                }
            }
            else{
                $this->Flash->error(__('XXXX'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
            }
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('XXXXX'));
    }
}
```

The problem I have right now is that I can´t seem to read out the redirectURL - because every time I come from a Link that requires a Logged in User I get forwarded to the adresses index which is defined in my AppController. But I need it to redirect to the adminindex.

Can I switch the Fallback for admin and user. Or does somebody know how to check if the redirectUrl isset ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`redirectUrl` is a function in the `AuthComponent` not a variable, so I think you need to add parentheses in the `isset` checks.

```
if (isset($this->Auth->redirectUrl()))
```